# What are the methods to crack WPA and WPA2?

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wpa2, wireless

Is there any method other than brute force and dictionary attacks to break WPA and WPA2?

Answer (score 5):

Cracking WPA/WPA2 can be done pretty quickly using the [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) suite which conveniently come packaged with the [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) penetration testing live operating system. Take note that you will need a wireless card that has a [compatible chipset](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Drivers).

There are plenty of articles on the internet on cracking WPA/WPA2 key but I've personally found that [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrkKpRdS1iQ) videos are the easiest to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Most approaches to attacking (good) encryption schemes rely on a degree of brute force.  The trick is to reduce the number of attempts necessary to break it.  Dictionary and Rainbow Table attacks are both brute force attacks that yield good results against insecure wireless passwords by attacking the handshake message in WPA and WPA2.  I am not aware of any other attacks that are more efficient than these two.